# Binary Output from Curl

Tags: php, curl

When I executed the command:

```
curl https://piwik.openstreetmap.org/piwik.php?idsite=1
```

I received a warning that binary output can mess up my terminal, which, yes it did having ignored the warning, so my first question is why does binary output mess up the terminal?

I then passed the output to a text file as follows:

```
curl https://piwik.openstreetmap.org/piwik.php?idsite=1 > binaryFrom_Openstreetmap_php.txt
```

And this did not result in erroneous output, rather the verbose output in the terminal was:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    43  100    43    0     0     17      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    17
```

Now the second question is, having observed the following to be the content of the text file:

```
GIF89a  €        !ù    ,       D ;
```

How is this binary when there are more than two characters? Unless I've been misusing the word binary my entire life, I cant discount that possibility entirely.

And thirdly, when viewed in a text editor on a Linux OS the characters are different to what is displayed when this file is viewed in a Windows 10 OS, why?

Comment: Generally, binary data = data that can't be decoded into normal text using some standard encoding. That's also why different characters are shown - default encodings tried by different systems are different.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try to get what you mean, so what you are saying it can only be decoded by some non standard encoding,  being as naïve as I am at this point I expected to see all 0's and 1's

Comment: Ok so yes I think this maybe a duplicate I love the unix philosophy yep that is definitely going on the fridge door